Obtaining other portion of my private key
I have only a partial private key due to hard drive damage. I have the full public key I plan to extrapolate back on the secp256k1 elliptic curve to locate the full private key. What are my chances of getting it correct?

It really depends on how much of the private key you're missing. Every missing byte increases the search space by a factor of 256. Assuming you can search one million keys every second (a reasonable approximation for a modern CPU utilizing all its cores running a decently optimized search algorithm):

4 missing bytes, 232 = 4,294,967,296 keys, about 1 hour to search through
5 missing bytes, 240 = 1,099,511,627,776 keys, about 12 days to search through
6 missing bytes, 248 = 281,474,976,710,656 keys, about 8 years to search through

As you can see, the chances of recovering the rest of the key within a reasonable timeframe fall pretty quickly. If there's a lot of funds to recover you can of course spend funds on acquiring more computing power, but even increasing it 256 times still offsets just one missing byte.

Thankyou. I will ponder my next step
